# Magento 2 : Issue on setup:di:compile

Tags: magento-2.2.5, setup-di-compile

When I run the command `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` I am getting an error as below

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111

Comment: please give more information.

Comment: When i am deploying  i got this error 
An error occurred during creating the deployment package, error message: Unable to execute command "php /tmp/builds/d-9965693d/bin/magento setup:di:compile 2>&1" -

Comment: please check it log what's error comes

Comment: Deleting var/generation, var/cache and var/di and try again

Comment: @SavanPatel Still not working

Comment: @RvSingh No log is generated

Comment: Make sure the PHP module intl is installed, clear var/generation and var/cache, enable Magento modules (bin/magento module:enable --all), compile DI (bin/magento setup:di:compile), and then try again.

Comment: The steps I did were the following to get rid of this issue.

First I re-installed Magento completely new then I did this:

removed var/generation and var/cache

switched to developer mode to recompile

And suddenly it worked fine

Comment: @RvSingh Can u tell me regarding php module?

Comment: which module install in last time? try to disable it

Comment: can u tell me what are you using php version and Apache or nginx   version.

Comment: I am using nginx

Comment: whats is your php version using? this error may because your  command line php version is different than magento2 is using currently. Example: Magento use PHP 7.0 (check phpinfo.php), and your command-line php version is different.(check command-line : php -v)

Answer (score 6):

If this happens regularly when you initiate compile and you're confident you have no errors I've found simply running `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` a second time will be successful.

Comment: Yeah this just started happening to me, not happy however it works everyother time is this a permissions thing maybe>

Answer (score 2):

Its due to improper module configuration. You can debug it by disabling recent modules that you installed and also check for missing files